# How to share posts (and plugins) between existing site and new, separate dev/test installation?

Tags: theme-development, customization, previews

- A client has an existing WP installation.
- I want to setup a dev/preview site that pulls same page/post content as existing site (and has same active plugins and settings), and I don't want the existing site to be affected.

How can I do this? Is is safe to do a separate WP install in a new directory and just feed it the same DB credentials (including WP table prefix) during the install process?

Comment: If you connect to the same DB, any content changes made on your dev site will be reflected in production.  A copy of the DB gives you all of the content and settings w/o the risk of changes to the current site.

Comment: Well...I want the content to be the same, between the sites, in case the client needs to update posts/pages (via existing site) during the dev process. For this phase of the project, I'll be focusing on framework/theme, rather than updating the content of the site.

Comment: I doubt it's possible to deny DB write abilities from your dev site.  I could be wrong.  If not, this means your "...I don't want the existing site to be affected" requirement is not possible if you simply share a DB.  This is a very common situation when a new theme is needed for a site and when performing other dev tasks.  Just pull a new copy of the DB every so often.  It's unlikely the dev site needs to be 100% in sync with production site content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tools available for simplifying the synchronization of databases between multiple WP installations, such as [WP Sync DB](http://wp-sync-db.github.io/).

As @jdm2112 mentioned, using a copy of the database—versus attempting to use the same database—reduces the risk of development work interfering with the production environment. However, simply making a copy of one site's WP database is generally insufficient for using it on another site. You can read more about [moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) here.